# How can I add daily limit of downloads to a user?

Tags: php

So I really need help I bought some PHP file manager and I found out that this function is missing so I cannot use it. I know HTML a lot but PHP is a new thing for me so any help would be great. I need to add a daily limit for each user of downloads.
Some code below from the file I think is the one to modify(but not sure):

```
<?php

if (!class_exists('Downloader', false)) {

    class Downloader
    {
        /**
        * Checks if file is under user folder
        *
        * @param string $checkPath path to check
        *
        * @return true/false
        */
        public function subDir($checkPath)
        {
            global $gateKeeper;

            if ($gateKeeper->getUserInfo('dir') == null) {
                return true;
            } else {
                $userdirs = json_decode($gateKeeper->getUserInfo('dir'), true);
                foreach ($userdirs as $value) {
                    $pos = strpos($checkPath, $value);
                    if ($pos !== false) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        /**
        * The safe way
        *
        * @param string $checkfile file to check
        * @param string $path      relative path to call the functionf from /ajax/
        *
        * @return true/false
        */
        public function checkFile($checkfile, $path = '')
        {
            global $setUp;
            $fileclean = base64_decode($checkfile);
            $file = $path.'../'.urldecode($fileclean);

            $filepathinfo = Utils::mbPathinfo($fileclean);

            $filename = $filepathinfo['basename'];
            $safedir = $filepathinfo['dirname'];
            $safedir = str_replace(array('/', '.'), '', $safedir);
            $realfile = realpath($file);

            $realsetup = realpath($path.'.'.$setUp->getConfig('starting_dir'));

            $avoidDir = array('vfm-admin', 'etc');
            $avoidFile = array('index.php', 'vfm-thumb.php', '.htaccess', '.htpasswd');

            if (strpos($realfile, $realsetup) !== false
                && !in_array($safedir, $avoidDir) 
                && !in_array($filename, $avoidFile)
                && file_exists($file)
            ) {

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        /**
        * Check download lifetime
        *
        * @param string $time time to check
        *
        * @return true/false
        */
        public function checkTime($time)
        {
            global $setUp;

            $lifedays = (int)$setUp->getConfig('lifetime');
            $lifetime = 86400 * $lifedays;
            if (time() <= $time + $lifetime) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        /**
        * Get file info before processing download
        *
        * @param string $getfile file to download
        * @param string $playmp3 check audio
        *
        * @return $headers array
        */
        public function getHeaders($getfile, $playmp3 = false)
        {
            $headers = array();

            $audiofiles = array('mp3','wav');
            $trackfile = './'.urldecode(base64_decode($getfile));
            $file = '.'.$trackfile;

            $filepathinfo = Utils::mbPathinfo($file);
            $filename = $filepathinfo['basename'];
            $dirname = $filepathinfo['dirname'].'/';
            $ext = $filepathinfo['extension'];
            $file_size = Utils::getFileSize($file);
            $disposition = 'inline';

            if (strtolower($ext) == 'pdf') {
                $content_type = 'application/pdf';
            } elseif (strtolower($ext) == 'zip') {
                $content_type = 'application/zip';
                $disposition = 'attachment';
            } elseif (in_array(strtolower($ext), $audiofiles)
                && $playmp3 == 'play'
            ) {
                $content_type = 'audio/mp3';
            } else {
                $content_type = 'application/force-download';
            }
            $headers['file'] = $file;
            $headers['filename'] = $filename;
            $headers['file_size'] = $file_size;
            $headers['content_type'] = $content_type;
            $headers['disposition'] = $disposition;
            $headers['trackfile'] = $trackfile;
            $headers['dirname'] = $dirname;

            return $headers;
        }

        /**
        * Download files
        *
        * @param string $file         path to download
        * @param string $filename     file name
        * @param string $file_size    file size
        * @param string $content_type header content type
        * @param string $disposition  header disposition
        * @param bool   $android      android device
        *
        * @return file served
        */
        public function download(
            $file,
            $filename,
            $file_size,
            $content_type,
            $disposition = 'inline',
            $android = false
        ) {
            // Gzip enabled may set the wrong file size.
            if (function_exists('apache_setenv')) {
                @apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
            }
            if (ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) {
                @ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
            }
            @set_time_limit(0);
            session_write_close();
            header("Content-Length: ".$file_size);

            if ($android) {
                header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"");
            } else {
                header("Content-Type: $content_type");
                header("Content-Disposition: $disposition; filename=\"".$filename."\"");
                header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
                header("Expires: -1");
            }
            if (ob_get_level()) {
                ob_end_clean();
            }
            readfile($file);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a coding service. Moreover, your requirement is very broad and can be implemented in a lot of different ways. If you want a chance to get an answer, you should first make some research, try to implement your own solution and come back once you have a specific problem and a precise question the community can help you with. Have a look at [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If you are using a framework you can do a listener that listens to the Downloader class and saves the downloads in the database for each user!

Comment: If you don't know PHP and need to modify some PHP-code, you should hire a developer.

Comment: Where can I hire someone?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new table/column in Database in which you would store amount of downloads for user (how many times he already downloaded). Number with limit of downloads you can keep in const variable or in DB too, depends how you want to manage that.
Then, everytime that user wants to download file, just make simple check - alreadyDownloadedTimes >= limitDownloadTimes in simple if statement.

Profit of having limit in DB is that you can make function in admin panel to easily change its value in DB instead of diving into code.

There is too much code to write it here so I will point it:
 1. Create column with number representing limit of downloads (in new Table - you can combine it with other limits)
 2. Create column with number representing how many times user already downloaded (needs to be updated when user downloads).
 3. Make queries for UPDATE (when user downloads) and SELECT (for number representing limit) + optionally queries for managing these limits (if you want to have full control in admin panel or you have premium accounts etc.)
 4. Everytime that user downloads file, make simple check if limit is reached - if not, let it go, if yes, block the download option.
 5. Make cron job for reseting that value in DB (amount of downloads per user) every 24hrs

Comment: Thanks, that is a little hard for me, because PHP is a new thing for me and all data are stored in PHP like there are no databases like MySQL etc.

Comment: If you need to use the phrase _"There is too much code to write it here"_, then the question is too unspecific and broad, which means that it should be closed (for being too broad) instead of answered.